# Drag and Drop Control in with RightToLeftLayout True

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, drag-and-drop

I used following code to drag and drop Button in C# and it works like charm when my Form.RightToLeftLayout=False,
but 
when I set RightToLeftLayout=True
it doesnt work and move the control in wrong direction!!!

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int xPosition;
        int yPosition;
        bool isDraged;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnMoveable_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
            xPosition = e.X;
            yPosition = e.Y;
            isDraged = true;
        }

        private void btnMoveable_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isDraged = false;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

        }


        private void btnMoveable_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isDraged)
            {

                btnMoveable.Left = btnMoveable.Left + e.X - xPosition;
                btnMoveable.Top = btnMoveable.Top + e.Y - yPosition;

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The BEST button drag and drop code I've found in my past couple hours searching.  Thank you for posting a working solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're discovering how RightToLeft is implemented.  Everything is still in their normal logical position but the coordinate system is mirror-imaged along the Y-axis.  So movement along the X-axis is inverted.  You'll need to accommodate that.  Fix:

```
    int dx = e.X - xPosition;
    if (this.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes) dx = -dx;
    btnMoveable.Left = btnMoveable.Left + dx;
```